# Bootstrap menu get stuck

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I began to create a simple webpage using bootstrap. I am beginner in web development. My first issue is:

- logo image: I cannot figure out how to make it responsive. What did I missed. I tried different position: absolute, static, relative. Nothing changes. I would like to have it responsive until medium screen and after disappeared for small screen.
- nav menu: I imported a menu from bootstrap documentation. I tried to float it right but it doesn't move. I would like to create a simple menu without any background that collapse for mobile device

Please don't hesitate to point every mistakes in my code. I am following a web design course in Coursera from 2015 so may be things are not very actual.
What should I do customize it well ?

thank for your help

Here is my page https://hardcore-wiles-5f54d6.netlify.app/

Here is my css:

```
 enter code here

 *{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 body{
 font-family: font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 }


 h2{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 margin-top: 3%;
 text-align: center;
 }

 a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#564C3A;
 }

 a:hover {
 color: #93918C;
 text-decoration: none;
 }

 article{
 text-align: justify;
 margin: 3% 10% 3% 10%;
 }

 article p{
 margin-top: 3%;
 }

 #header-nav{
 background-color: #F5F3EF;
 padding: 0%;
 }

 #logo-img{
 background: url('../images/permacultivons-logo.png') no-repeat;
 width: 160px;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: 180px;
 margin: 0% 0 -5% -150%;
 }

.navbar-brand{
padding-top: 30px;
margin-left: -40%;
}

.navbar-brand h1{
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
font-size: 2.5em;
text-shadow: .5px .5px .5px #000;
line-height: .75;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-brand p{
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
font-size: 1.5em;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-bottom: 0;
line-height: .75;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: @WaisKamal Thank you for your answer. I know media queries but I am little bit confused with bootstrap framework (row, col, etc..). Fortunately, i could find a course more recent. I am gonna re-start my project with some better foundation :)